# Regex for replacing Row numbers (1. & 2.) only in string

Tags: java, regex, regexp-replace

In one of my scenario , I wanted to replace specific strings mentioned below.

```java
String S1 = "1.This is example of regex and call the mobile 400-199-1234.This statement is valid.2.This is second example of regex.10.This is tenth statement";
```

In the above string I wanted to replace `1.`, `2.`, `10.` (only) with null value.

The String should like this

```java
String S1 = "This is example of regex and call the mobile 400-199-1234.This statement is valid. This is second example of regex.This is tenth statement";
```

I have tried using the below regex - `"[0-9]\\."`

My Code looks like: `S1=S1.replaceAll("[0-9]\\.","")`

It replaces all values including the mobile number and the string looks like this:

```java
String S1 = "This is example of regex and call the mobile 400-199-123This statement is valid. This is second example of regex.This is tenth statement";
```

Can someone help with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure there should be no hyphen before the number to be removed, you can use a lookbehind with a word boundary on the left:

```java
S1 = S1.replaceAll("\\b(?<!-)\\d+\\.", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkxoaZ/1). The `\b(?<!-)` part makes sure there is no word and `-` char before the removed number.

If there can be valid numbers with dots after that are preceded with hyphens, add a `\d` pattern before `-`:

```java
S1 = S1.replaceAll("\\b(?<!\\d-)\\d+\\.", "");
```

to make sure the number is not matched after a digit + `-` char.